# How do I setup an external tool in Android Studio to decompile a project's native code

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, decompiler

I'm trying to write some code using NEON intrinsics / assembly and would like to iterate fast by quickly viewing the assembly code generated by Clang for a specific function. I'm using the standard process for writing C/C++ code using Android Studio and am using `gradle-experimental-0.7.0-rc1` (if that makes a difference).

I was able to setup an "External Tool" to run `objdump` from within AndroidStudio - but there were a few different problems:

- The AndroidStudio toolchain can generate different kinds of binary files depending on the target platform (x86, arm, arm-v7, etc). Each binary has a different `objdump` decompiler. Is there a way to switch binaries when defining an external tool?
- The output of `objdump` shows up in the terminal window at the bottom. Is there a way to show the decompiled output as a regular file in the IDE?
- Is there a better UI that let's me move around between the different functions?